# Combinatorial Proofs: Show that $\binom{n}{j+1}(j+1) = \binom{n}{n-j}(n-j)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

I'm not sure if I understand why the following proof holds and I'm not sure where to start:

$$
{n \choose j+1 } (j+1) = {n \choose n-j} (n-j)
$$

Would appreciate any help and why this does hold (in particular the movements that allow the switches to happen... like does just saying j+1 = n-j work?)

Edit: Sorry, forgot to mention that I cannot use the identity:
$$
{n \choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
$$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to mention that I can't use this identity. The textbook asks to solve this using only the fact that $${n \choose k}$$ is the number of k-subsets of an n-set

Answer (score 1):

Both sides count, for example, the number of ways of building a team of $j$ regular players and a captain from a roster of $n$ available athletes.

The left hand side can be interpreted as picking a team of $j+1$ players from $n$ available, and then selecting a team captain from among those players: the $\binom{n}{j+1}$ picks the players, and then you have $j+1$ ways to pick the captain.

The right hand side can be interpreted as first picking everyone who will not be a regular player in the team (by picking $n-j$ people who won't be players), and then picking from among them who will be the captain (you have $n-j$ ways of doing that).

In both cases, you end up picking a team with $j$ regular players and a captain from a roster of $n$ potential athletes.

Comment: Thank you! Does a reasoning explanation like this equal a proof? I completely understand what you're saying but as there are no numbers and just reasoning, would this be equal to what a textbook might write as a proof?

Comment: @Coco I do not know your textbook, I do not know the standards your course may set, and I do not know how you defined these items (since you say you cannot use the numerical formula). If you defined the binomial coefficients merely in terms of "it counts `blah`", then any argument about equality would necessarily have to involve describing what it counts, in the terms you defined them. If you defined it as counting subsets, you would have to re-cast the explanation in terms of subsets, not in terms of teams and captains, for example.